# How to pass value/argument to the map function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to pass varible in map function using javascript

```
var obj = ["Singapore", "Malaysia"]
var pr = ["SG", "MY"] // need to pass value to map function
render(){
 obj.map((val, pr)=>{
  return html`
        <p id="pr">val</p>
}
```

Comment: The second value in the map callback is the *index*, which would allow you to access the value you want from `pr` (if you hadn't shadowed it by also naming the index `pr`).

Comment: Read this! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

As [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) already stated in a comment: The second parameter of the function you hand to the `map` function is the *index* of the object you use map on. You can read about the parameters in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters).

So a solution would be to use this index to access the values of another array like this:

```
var obj = ["Singapore", "Malaysia"]
var pr = ["SG", "MY"] // need to pass value to map function
render(){
 obj.map((val, index) => {
  abbr = pr[index];

  // abbr will get the values "SG", "MY" whatsoever
}
```

You just have to watchout that your obj and pr arrays have the same size and are sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned the second argument to `map` is the `index` of the element of the current iteration, and it doesn't look like you need it in your example. However, what you might find useful is placing the names/code into the same object and `map`ping over an array of those objects instead. That way related information stays together.

```
var arr = [{ name: 'Singapore', code: 'SG' }, { name: 'Malaysia', code: 'MY' }];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return arr.map(({ name, code }) => {
      return html`<p id="${code}">${name}</p>`;
    });
  }
}
```

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/6j0myx6wyw)